# Django дата публикации постов

Tags: python, html, django

[image: Нажимаю на blogs в /admin/]
[image: Ввожу /blog/]

файл models.py:

```py
from django.db import models


class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField()
```

Не работает `date`, работает `data`.

файл all_blogs.html:

```html
Hello blog

{% for blog in blogs %}
  <h2>{{ blog.title }}</h2>
  <h5>{{ blog.date }}</h5>
  <p>{{ blog.description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Занимаюсь по уроку -
Когда запускаю `python manage.py runserver`, у меня ошибка когда указываю значение `date` в классе `Blog`, чтобы создать в `/admin/` дату поста, когда указываю `data`, всё работает, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выглядит так, будто вы добавили поле `date`, но забыли создать его в базе данных. Выполните:

```
./manage.py makemigrations --dry-run
```

Команда покажет есть ли изменения в ваших моделях, которые не отражены в БД. Если есть, то сгенерируйте и примените миграции:

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Спасибо, да я проводил последовательностью команд ./manage.py makemigrations, ./manage.py migrate
Но всё равно выдавало ошибку, но удалив БД и произвел эти манипуляции ещё раз у меня всё заработало,видимо в прошлый раз они не сохранялись, это ошибка была со стороны БД ?